# javascript stop all functions when game is over

Tags: javascript

I need to stop this function from executing:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {

    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    checkKey(charStr);

    //check loss
    if (attempt == 0) {
        gameLost();
    }

    //check win
    underscoreRemain = nameReform.includes("_");
    if (!underscoreRemain) {
        gameWon();
    }

    document.getElementById("attempt").innerHTML = attempt;
});
```

Basically, when the game is either won or lost, it won't take any more key pressed, hence no execution of the rest of my functions. I've looked on w3school and stackoverflow, but the removeEnventListener and other suggested methods don't work.

Comment: Why dont you just exit out of the web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the event listener by passing the *original function object* to `removeEventListener` at the appropriate time.

Notice that I gave the function a name.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function handler(evt) {

    // evt = evt || window.event; // This line is unnecessary

    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    checkKey(charStr);

    //check loss
    if (attempt == 0) {
        gameLost();

        // Remove the listener
        this.removeEventListener(event.type, handler);
    }

    //check win
    underscoreRemain = nameReform.includes("_");
    if (!underscoreRemain) {
        gameWon();

        // Remove the listener
        this.removeEventListener(event.type, handler);
    }

    document.getElementById("attempt").innerHTML = attempt;
});
```